# Guaranteeing data type size

Tags: c++, arrays, types

Is there a correct or conventional way to guarantee a data type will be sizeof 4?

Previously I had just done some typedef statements based upon sizeof different data types, and I was wondering if there is a better or more conventional method to have data types of a pre determined size on different architectures?

For the sake of this question lets say I have a large array of chars that I have read from a file. I want to read a series of 24 bit Integers from this char array. In the past I have casted the array to a data type with a sizeof my desired data type, this method fails however if there is no primitive data type with my desired size.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
  char x[10] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
  uint32_t* y = (uint32_t*)x;
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)std::cout << "y: " << y[i] << "\n";

  output:
  y: 16843009
  y: 16843009
  y: 257

  desired output:
  y: 65793
  y: 65793
  y: 65793
   ....
```

Comment: `uint32_t` is not good enough?

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @barakmanos there are a slew of fixed-width integer types in [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: If I read 32 bit integers from a list of 24 bit integers wouldn't all of my values be off?

Comment: @barakmanos `uint32_t` exists if it can have 32 bits which might not be 4 bytes because of `CHAR_BIT != 8`, although it's an ephemeral possibility.

Comment: @Nick Is it a binary file or text one?

Comment: @barakmanos It is a binary file

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `sizeof (unsigned char[4]) == 4`, guaranteed. `sizeof (uint32_t) == 32 / CHAR_BIT` *if* `uint32_t` exists; this is 4 if `CHAR_BIT == 8` (which is very likely the case).

Answer (score 0):

Go old school and read-a-byte, read-a-byte, read-a-byte-byte-byte!

```
uint32_t read24(unsigned char *& bufp)
{
    uint32_t val;
    val = *bufp++;
    val |= *bufp++ << 8;
    val |= *bufp++ << 16;
    return val;
}
```

Usage:

```
unsigned char buffer[] = 
{ 0x2A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x9A, 0x02, 0x00, 0x4E, 0x61, 0xBC };
unsigned char * bufp = buffer;
uint32_t A = read24(bufp);
uint32_t B = read24(bufp);
uint32_t C = read24(bufp);
```

Why unsigned `char`s? Easiest way to deal with sign extension. If you use signed `char`s, you have to do masking like this:

```
val = *bufp++ & 0xFF;
```

to strip off the extra sign bits.

And watch out for endian. Depending on where your data is coming from you might have to read everything in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed-width type `uint32_t` is designed for this. It will be constructed from whatever primitive is appropriate on your system.

You can find it in `<cstdint>` or, pre-C++11, in Boost as `<boost/cstdint.hpp>. C also provides a`` that may be of use.

Failing that, `char[4]`?